# NGINX redirect returns 414 Request-URI Too Large

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I'm not an NGINX's expert, I'm trying to redirect an entire website from a domain to another domain.

To test the solution in local I'm using two different urls:

- fake old domain -> 127.0.0.3
- fake new domain -> 127.0.0.1

But when I use the code below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name 127.0.0.3;
    return 301 $scheme://127.0.0.1$request_uri;
}
```

I see this error:

> 414 Request-URI Too Large

[image]

How I can solve it?

NGINX is inside a Docker container that manage two different services as indicated below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    #server_name  domain.me www.domain.me;
    server_name  127.0.0.1; # FOR STAGING ONLY

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://website:8301; # The port must be the same of PROJECT_PORT
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        # max uploadable file size
        client_max_body_size 4G;
    }

    location /static/ {
        # static folder on the server
        alias /app/web/static-folder/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        # media folder on the server
        alias /app/web/media-folder/;
    }
}

server {
    #server_name  geoserver.domain.me www.geoserver.domain.me;
    server_name 127.0.0.2; # FOR STAGING ONLY

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_tokens off;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        application/json
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        text/xml application/xm
        application/xml+rss
        text/javascript;

    underscores_in_headers on;
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 1k;
    proxy_buffers 24 4k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 8k;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 32k;

    location / {
            deny all;
            return 301 /geoserver;
    }

    location /geoserver {
        proxy_pass         http://geoserver:8080/geoserver;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I report the complete conf below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    #server_name  domain.me www.domain.me;
    server_name  127.0.0.3; # FOR STAGING ONLY
    return 301 $scheme://127.0.0.1$request_uri;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://website:8301; # The port must be the same of PROJECT_PORT
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        # max uploadable file size
        client_max_body_size 4G;
    }

    location /static/ {
        # static folder on the server
        alias /app/web/static-folder/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        # media folder on the server
        alias /app/web/media-folder/;
    }
}

server {
    #server_name  geoserver.domain.me www.geoserver.domain.me;
    server_name 127.0.0.2; # FOR STAGING ONLY

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_tokens off;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        application/json
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        text/xml application/xm
        application/xml+rss
        text/javascript;

    underscores_in_headers on;
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 1k;
    proxy_buffers 24 4k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 8k;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 32k;

    location / {
            deny all;
            return 301 /geoserver;
    }

    location /geoserver {
        proxy_pass         http://geoserver:8080/geoserver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the URL in the browser.

You are redirecting from `/` to `/domain`. You want to redirect to `https://domain/`

When your browser connects to `127.0.0.3`, it gets a redirect to `/127.0.0.1`. It should get a redirect to `https://127.0.0.1`.

In such cases it's useful to use browser debug tools or curl to check what the *actual* response is, vs. expected response.

Comment: Please, can you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you, the theory is clear, but what about how I solve the trouble? What I've to change on the code above?

Comment: Read through the config, and figure out where your redirect happens, and what it looks like.